# GCP Pubsub num of undelivered messages wont change

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using pubsub to trigger a cloud function that I have defined to have maximum of 10 instances.

When a bulk of around 300 messages or more arrive to the topic and start triggering the function, suddenly the number of unacked messages stops going, it just doesn't change, although I know that my cloud functions that are triggered are automatically acking those messages...

I'm wondering what I'm missing here...

Adding the following chart to show what I'm talking about:
[image]

So there are few things to notice here:

- the chart is in 1 min intervals
- the scale for the chart is on the right side
- the toolbox on the left is just so it will be easy to see what colour corresponds to what line
- ack_message_count (blue) is the number of acks my cloud functions are performing each minute
- send_message_operation_count (green) is the number of messages published into the topic that is triggering the cloud function

  - notice the spike around 1:01 PM, this is the bulk that is send into the topic, its around 1k new messages
  - aside from the that bulk, there are constantly new messages entering the topic, but much less than the number of acks that is performed
- push_request_count (orange) is the number of time pubsub tries to trigger the cloud function (be it successful or resulting in 429 which means that it has reached the maximum number of instances running)
- num_undelivered_messages (pink) is the number of unacked messages that are waiting inside the queue of the subscription

First I though maybe I just don't perform enough acks with my cloud functions, but that is not the case since there is much more acks than new messages after the peak of the 1k messages.

What I thought I would see is just a steady decline of the number of unacked messages in the subscription's queue.

So essentially what I don't understand is why does the num_undelivered_messages doesn't go down as the number of acks continues (1:01 - 1:10), and then, suddenly it just drops (1:10 - 1:15) really fast?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from the graph, your acknowledging of messages cannot keep up with the volume of the messages being published. An example is at 1:05-1:10 where there are still messages being published (green line) but the acknowledgement rate (blue line) did not increase, thus an increase of unacknowledged messages (pink line).

I suggest to increase your [cloud function memory](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#memory) if it is not yet at the maximum which is 8GB.